# BigQuery - Convert Datetime to local timezone?

Tags: sql, datetime, google-bigquery, timezone-offset

I have a DateTime column with data like "2020-08-05T10:19:30" in UTC.

I need to convert this to either "America/Los Angeles" or "America/Chicago" timezone with a BigQuery SQL call.

I've tried:

```
SELECT A, B, C, DATETIME(date_field,"America/Los Angeles") as new_date_field FROM table;
```

I get this:

> "No matching signature for function DATETIME for argument types:
> DATETIME, STRING. Supported signatures: DATETIME(INT64, INT64, INT64,
> INT64, INT64, INT64); DATETIME(DATE, TIME); DATETIME(TIMESTAMP,
> [STRING]); DATETIME(DATE); DATETIME(DATETIME); DATETIME(STRING)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below

```
SELECT A, B, C, 
  DATETIME(timestamp(date_field),"America/Chicago") as new_date_field 
FROM table;
```

Answer (score 1):

You're seeing the error because your data is already in a datetime data type and that is not a valid data type for the datetime function.  Instead try the following:

```
with sample_data as (
select  DATETIME("2020-08-05T10:19:30") as date_field
)
select  datetime(timestamp(date_field), "America/Los_Angeles") from sample_data
```

Answer (score 1):

> Just change the date-time format **'%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S'** and the zone
> **'Asia/Kolkata'** below and run it. Find the example below for Indian Standard Time (IST).

BigQuery Command

```
select format_timestamp('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S IST', datetime(timestamp_micros(event_timestamp), "Asia/Kolkata")) as time from table
```